# My App Will Not Run in Background

Tags: ios, background, info.plist

I am having an issue where my app will not run in the background. My app used to run in the background before I changed some settings. Now I can not get it back to how it was originally. I have even tried creating a new project, same result. In my `info.plist` I have the `Application does not run in background` row, but it does not seem to work.

Another interesting fact - The app will run in the background for my iOS simulator, but not on any actual device.

Thanks!

Comment: There are 2 types of background: 1. when you press Home button, will the App be killed? this is related to `Application does not run in background` settings; 2. background activities like getting user location etc, that is background service. Which background type are you looking for?

Comment: I am wanting my application sound to keep playing, and a timer function I have to keep running. If I pressed the home button currently, it does not kill the app, but will more or less pause the app.

Comment: Then it's not related to `Application does not run in background`. Read [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial) tutorial.

Comment: I did follow all of those steps.. Still won't run. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please show your codes by **editing** your question

Comment: I don't have any code that would affect this.. That's the problem

Comment: You have to register for background mode before you can use it .

Comment: I have turned on the background mode and updated my `info.plist`. There is more I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing `Application does not run in background` from your **info.plist** ?

i.e. Actually deleting the row.